# Webpage images not displaying in android firefox browser

Tags: android, html, firefox

I have a site that when I view it in firefox on an android device the images are not coming up. The images are hosted on another site. If I view the same page in chrome or the default browser, they come up just fine. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you please post the HTML and any css styling also. I think I know what it is but would need to see code.

Comment: $display .= "<img src=\"" .$row->app_image_url. "\" />"; is the php method that is building the image element. Full code can be found here http://github.com/jrock2004/aaa-app-list

Comment: Ok, so looking at the image url, I think the problem may be there. Here is an example of one of them which is a link to a google play store image. https://lh5.ggpht.com/1VhqQ-1fkKiwyKArSt93edMWdeNO9MIl07Eqfyxvh-_bll6DcltyxjF6l2ScTbaacRmO=w300-rw

Comment: Looks like it's serving a webp file format which is only compatible with Chrome but not Firefox (or IE). Can you change it to a PNG or have a PNG alternative for non-Chrome browsers?